# how to start docker container with detach for docker-java?

Tags: docker, docker-java

I am trying to run a docker image using the following code. But the container is exiting immediately after starting. I don't find `-d` params at creating container. how to do?

```
HostConfig hostConfig = new HostConfig();
DefaultDockerClientConfig.Builder config = DefaultDockerClientConfig.createDefaultConfigBuilder();
DockerClient dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance(config).build();
CreateContainerCmd createContainerCmd = dockerClient.createContainerCmd(image);
createContainerCmd.withTty(true)
.withAttachStdout(true)
.withStdinOpen(true)
.withAttachStdout(true)
.withAttachStderr(true)
.withAttachStdin(true)
.withName(containerName)
.withHostConfig(hostConfig);
String containerId = createContainerCmd.exec().getId();
dockerClient.startContainerCmd(containerId).exec();
```

Could anybody help me to understand the how to keep the container up and running?

Comment: The Docker API doesn't have "run in the foreground" as an option, and so the various Docker SDKs frequently don't either.  "Keep the container running" isn't an option _per se_, but if the container exits it means the process inside the container is exiting too.  Have you looked at things like the `docker logs` of the container that gets started (could be from outside your application)?  Have you verified the `image` runs independently with these options (`docker run -it image`)?

Comment: @DavidMaze  thanks your attention,my  image's `docker-entrypoint.sh` just do `echo`. I change `nginx:latest` image, container keep running. When i add  `while [1]` in my `docker-entrypoint.sh`, container keep running too, but `execStartCmd` is no effect. As if i should write a event handling service.  I am confused.

Comment: @xuexue were you able to solve this problem?